# Getting 404 trying http PUT using Node Express Postgresql

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, express, put

Edit: NEVERMIND - I made a small mistake in the Angular service. My bad.

I'm trying to teach myself more backend by building a simple CMS using angular, Node and Express, and PostgreSql. I figured out how to do achieve all the CRUD functionality except UPDATE. I thought I understood what to do but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I keep getting a 404. What am I misunderstanding or going about the wrong way? I know this is simple but I'm pretty new so any help in understanding where I'm getting confused is really appreciated. Here's the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="updateBlogEntry(specificBlog.id, specificBlog.title, specificBlog.author, specificBlog.imageurl, specificBlog.content)">
    <h2>Title:</h2>
        <input type="text" ng-model="specificBlog.title"></input>
      <br>
    <h3>Author:</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="specificBlog.author"></input>
      <br>
    <h3>Photo:</h3>
        <input type="text" ng-model="specificBlog.imageurl"></input>
      <br>
    <h3>Content:</h3>
      <textarea type="text" rows="5" cols="50" ng-model="specificBlog.content">
      </textarea>
      <br>
    <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
  </form>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
  var id = $stateParams.id;
  var title = $stateParams.title;
  var author = $stateParams.author;
  var imageurl = $stateParams.imageurl;
  var content = $stateParams.content;

  $scope.updateBlogEntry = function(id, title, author, imageurl, content) {
    adminService.updateBlogEntry(id, title, author, imageurl, content);
  }
```

**Angular Service**

```
this.updateBlogEntry = function(id, title, author, imageurl, content) {
    return $http({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: 'updateBlogEntry/' + id,
      data: {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        author: author,
        imageurl: imageurl,
        content: content
      }
    })
    .success(function(data) {
      alert("Entry Updated");
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      alert("Error Updating"); 
    })
```

**Server Index**

```
// EXTERNAL MODULES //
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var massive = require('massive');

// CONFIG //
var config = require('./config');

// EXPRESS //
var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + './../dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// MASSIVE //
var massiveUri = config.MASSIVE_URI;
var massiveServer = massive.connectSync({
    connectionString: massiveUri
});
app.set('db', massiveServer);
var db = app.get('db');

var dbSetup = require('./services/dbSetup');
dbSetup.run();

// CONTROLLERS //
var userCtrl = require('./controllers/userCtrl');
var blogCtrl = require('./controllers/blogCtrl');


// Blog Endpoints //
app.post('/api/createBlogEntry', blogCtrl.createBlogEntry);
app.get('/api/getBlogEntries', blogCtrl.readBlogEntries);
app.get('/api/getBlogEntry/:id', blogCtrl.readBlogEntry);
// BUG Why isn't this working?
app.put('/api/updateBlogEntry/:id', blogCtrl.updateBlogEntry);

// CONNECTIONS //
var port = config.PORT;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**Node Controller**

```
updateBlogEntry: function(req, res, next){
        db.blogs.blog_update([
            req.params.id,
            req.body.title,
            req.body.author,
            req.body.imageurl,
            req.body.content
        ],
        function(err, results){
            if (err){
                console.error(err);
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.send(results[0]);
            }
        })
    }
```

**blog_update.sql**

```
UPDATE blogs
set
  title     = COALESCE($2, title),
  author    = COALESCE($3, author),
  imageurl  = COALESCE($4, imageurl),
  content   = COALESCE($5, content)
WHERE id = $1

RETURNING * ;
```

**The error in the console:**

```
angular.js:11881 PUT http://localhost:3000/updateBlogEntry/1 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `http://localhost:3000/api/updateBlogEntry/1` :p

Comment: The console error?

Comment: No this part 
` url: 'updateBlogEntry/' + id,`
It should be 
 url: '/api/updateBlogEntry/' + id,

As per your express routes

Comment: YES! That worked! Man, I knew it was something small I just wasn't seeing! Thank you.

Comment: Added as answer :) you are welcomed .

Comment: what is postico, post your code for get.

Comment: I actually just figured that out after writing that, thanks again though!

Comment: you are welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written your URL wrong.

It should be /api/updateBlogEntry as per your Node's express routes.

change this part

```
` url: 'updateBlogEntry/' + id,`
```

It should be

`url: '/api/updateBlogEntry/' + id,`